# Cleaner way to create dictionary from zip iterables in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a lists of data, which I need to use in a function that returns a dictionary. The returned dictionary needs to be appended to a list.

```
dictionary_big_list = [] 

for i, j, k in zip(lst1, lst2, lst3):
     returned_dictionary = dictionary_create_function(i, j, k)
     dictionary_big_list.append(returned_dictionary)
```

I am looking for a cleaner way to apply the logic. The lists are the same length.

Comment: please define `lst1`, `lst2`,`lst3` and provide the expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `map` with multiple iterables:

```
dic_big_list = list(map(dic_create_function, list1, list2, list3))
```